# PHP installed correctly but php code still not processed, am I missing something?

Tags: php

When I test my code in a browser it just shows the php code in the browser, do I need an index.php or something? This is my first time coding with php, all I'm trying to do is set up a simple contact form that will email me but I cant get the php code to process, what am I missing?

Edit: I have mamp installed and it says the apache server is on, I just get the php code in my browser window

Comment: Do you have a server?

Comment: Did you set up a web server (Apache, nginx, ...)?

Comment: What have you installed to render php

Comment: Did you add an opening <?php tag at the top of the file?

Comment: Can we see your code? Try `<?php echo phpinfo();?>` see what output you get

Comment: Step 1: Create a file `test.php`, add `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it, and try to open it (if you're using WAMP/XAMPP or the similar, you'd want to load `localhost/test.php`. If it's hosted on a webserver, you'd want to load `domain.com/test.php` -- that'll tell you if PHP is working or not.

Comment: Which server you are using ...?? I guess Apache

Comment: Search for a tutorial on setting this up.

Comment: Make sure you are accessing the page via HTTP, not via the `file://` protocol.

Comment: Have you added `LoadModule php5_module "/path/to/php5apache2_4.dll"` and `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` in the appropriate places for the Apache configuration *and* restarted?

Answer (score 2):

Having PHP installed is not enough to do this, you will also need a web server (Apache being very common). You also will need to open and close php using

```
<?php 
?>
```

That is if you have not already.

I would suggest using the following code to test if it works:

```
<?php
   echo "Yes this works!";
?>
```

Save this as **`index.php`** and open it from your browser as you would open a webpage, if you see **Yes this works!** Then everything is running fine, other wise you have an issue not related to your PHP code.

Comment: I also used those tags correctly...I dont think its something server side, I think maybe in my form tag I may have done something wrong, here's what I put: <form method="POST" name="contactform" action="contact-form-handler.php">

Comment: @user2648540 I think you should check first <form> tag, If you are using it in a php block, followed by echo statement then I'll recommend you to replace your double quotes with single quotes, Check this It may work.

Answer (score 1):

Check your php code with a `test.php` file.
Write

```
<?php
     echo"My php file";
?>
```

Open this file in your web browser using localhost with your default port(80)
In this case you should write it as 
`http://localhost:80/test.php` 
If your test.php file is present in your www directory.

If your browser just renders this as a plain text 
 `echo"My php file";`
 then this means you don't have your server ready to process your php requests, Either your server(Maybe apache) is offline or you've just problems with your http ports.

For example If you are using Windows(Which by default comes with IIS (**Internet Information Services**) then your port 80 will not be easily available to you, then you can edit your **httpd.conf** file and change your port 80 to 81, and browse your php file at this port in this case you can write `http://localhost:81/test.php`

If you see just "php file" without an echo statement, this means you have installed server correctly, In this case your browser will only render
**My php file**

Alternatively you can turn off IIS server manually if you don't want to change your http:// ports by simple steps:

- Check whether your port 80 is free or not
- If it says your port 80 is free then your server can use it well
- If it says your port 80 is used by IIS then you can stop IIS server manually
- Then you will be able to use your php server

Comment: I tried this and it just showed me the php code in my browser, I'm sure I'm just missing something stupid but I cant figure out what it is

Comment: Please check availability of port 80, I think there is some problem in your server configuration, not in your syntax.